# FFmpeg matching encoding output between 2 vidoes

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding, handbrake

I am trying to replace a boot video from my device however I'm unable to get both videos to match despite my best efforts which causes the video not to show at all and I'm sure that the issue is caused by an encoding difference between the videos.

The original file output from ffprobe is as follows:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '[FOLDER]/1_powerup_2017_main.mp4':
Metadata:
 major_brand     : mp42
 minor_version   : 0
 compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
 creation_time   : 2016-12-07T20:39:51.000000Z
 encoder         : HandBrake 0.9.9 2013051800
 Duration: 00:00:11.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4789 kb/s
 Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1080x1920 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 4648 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2016-12-07T20:39:51.000000Z
  encoder         : JVT/AVC Coding
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 140 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2016-12-07T20:39:51.000000Z
```

Which I used the following command to attempt to create:

```
ffmpeg -i [INPUT]  -vf setsar=1,format=yuv420p -r 24 -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -brand mp42 -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 -colorspace bt709 [OUTPUT]
```

This command creates a video with the following ffprobe output:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '[FOLDER]/1_powerup_2017_main.mp4':
Metadata:
 major_brand     : mp42
 minor_version   : 512
 compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
 encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
 Duration: 00:00:06.34, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 988 kb/s
 Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1080x1920 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 972 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : VideoHandler
 Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 9 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Is this to do with the compatible_brands or is there a Handbrake preset that could be used that I didn't notice?

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Comment: Try with ffmpeg git build